# How to default to unpinned Remote Desktop connection bar?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

I just upgraded to a new computer (Windows 10).  On my old one (also Windows 10) when I remote desktop (full screen, all monitors) to another computer, the connection bar would default to unpinned.  It would appear if I hovered at the top of any screen, but otherwise was not visible.

Since my upgrade, my remote desktop session always comes up with the connection bar pinned.  I have to manually unpin it every session.  I tried changing the hide option, but that just makes it hidden all the time, which is definitely not desirable!  How can I get that old behavior of defaulting to unpinned, but show on top of screen hover?

Comment: Are you using mstsc.exe to do remote desktop, or the Microsoft Remote Desktop app from the Microsoft Store?

Comment: There's a different one available on the store?  I'm using mstsc.exe, the built-in one, same on both machines.

Comment: Yes, the one in the store is quite different. Works more like one you'd find on a phone or tablet. I think mstsc.exe is still better though.

Comment: I just tested it on my Windows 10 environment. When I first connect it indeed defaults to pinned. I unpin, move the mouse away so the bar goes away and then close the connection. Next time I connect to that machine, the connection is still unpinned. So it seems to be something on your end, not specifically to windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appears to have been a Windows 10 bug which was later corrected in a cumulative update.

Answer (score 10):

**Option 1: Add pinconnectionbar to your .rdp file**

> **Pinconnectionbar**
>
> This setting determines whether or not the connection bar should be
>   pinned to the top of the remote session upon connection.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> `pinconnectionbar:i:<value>`
>
> **Values**
>   Values   Explanation 
>   0 The connection bar should not be pinned to the top of the remote session. 
>   1 The connection bar should be pinned to the top of the remote session.
>
> https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff393714(v=ws.10).aspx

**Option 2: Add Value to Registry**

In `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client` add a DWORD value PinConnectionBar with the same values as above.  This option works the first time.  However, the Remote Desktop Client deletes the key afterwards.

Comment: While interesting and looking like it should be helpful...  No change.  No impact either way.  I still have a pinned connection bar on every startup whether or not the parameter is in place (with either value).

Comment: I added `pinconnectionbar:i:0` to Documents\Default.rdp (which is a hidden file).  The bar was unpinned for `:0` and pinned for `:1`.

Comment: As of Windows 10 version (20H2) dd 26 feb 2021, this doesn't;t seem to work anymore - see my answer belong.

Answer (score 5):

NOTE: In the 'current' (26 feb 2021) Windows 10 version (20H2) there (again) seems to be a 'bug' with the Remote Desktop Client, which as a result doesn't let it respect the RDP-setting `pinconnectionbar:I:<value>`.

However, it's still possible to use the registry to unpin the connection bar for ALL RDP-sessions: goto `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client`
and add the `dword` value `PinConnectionBar` (when it doesn't exist) and set the value to `0` to unpin all (future) remote desktop sessions.

As mentioned in another answer to this post, this key was expected to be removed after closing the session, but since the `pinconnectionbar` option of the RDP-file no longer works, this option seems to stick in the registry.

Comment: Command-line fix: `reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Terminal Server Client" /v "PinConnectionBar" /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f`